# Spring specification exists

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring Specification (and net.kaczmarzyk.specification-arg-resolver for auto spec creation) to make dynamic Endpoints.
I have run into the need to know if a specific Specification exists on the request already (both for testing and permissions).

Permissions:
Based on user access I sometime append specifications onto the requested on. However it would be nice to know if specific spec's were used and maybe even update or delete them.

Testing:
Would be nice to know after a function has run to validate if a spec got added like it should have.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The question is there a way to tell if a specific specification exists inside the specification object.  Secondly ... can your programmatically update or remove specific ones.

Comment: kind of like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153760/how-to-unit-test-method-using-spring-data-jpa-specifications
however this only mocks if a spec comes in i wanting to validate the mock coming in.